# Keep blank rows in table after filtering

Tags: filter, pivot-table, amazon-quicksight

I'm moving to Quicksight after years using Excel pivot tables to create dashboards, so I'm trying to replicate some of my old pivot tables using this new tool.

One of the difficulties I'm having is keeping rows with no values after filtering something.

For example, this table has four rows:

[image: table with four rows]

After filtering, the last two rows disappeared:

[image: table after filtering]

I want the last 2 rows to remain in the table, even if their values are null after filtering.

Is there a way to do this?

I need this so I can build a frame in the dashboard, without worrying that it may break if someone filters something.